# Loss of accuracy in modulus warning despite correct results

Tags: r

I wrote a recursive modular exponentiation by squaring function which works correctly but triggers warnings:

```
msquare <- function(x,n) (x*x) %% n

mod.exp <- function(a,k,n){
  ifelse(k <= 2,
       a^k %% n,
       ifelse(k %% 2 == 0,
            msquare(mod.exp(a,k %/% 2,n),n),
            (a * msquare(mod.exp(a,k %/% 2,n),n)) %% n))
}
```

I wrote it using `ifelse` so I could use it vectorized over the exponents:

```
powers <- mod.exp(2,1:348,349)
```

When I run the above code, it triggers numerous warnings like:

> In ifelse(k <= 2, a^k%%n, ifelse(k%%2 == 0, msquare(mod.exp(a,  ... : 
>   probable complete loss of accuracy in modulus

But when I look at the output (and compare it to that of Python's modular exponentiation function `pow()`) it is 100% correct. The calculation itself should never be taking the modulus of a number larger than `2*348^2 = 242208` which is way below the level at which this should even be an issue.

What causes these warnings and how can I avoid them? I know that I could rewrite it in a non-recursive way, which might help, though that would still leave the source of the warnings mysterious.

**On Edit** Somewhat oddly, the following code works warning-free:

```
powers <- sapply(1:348, function(x) mod.exp(2,x,349))
```

Somehow the recursive calls seem to be responsible for the warnings.

Comment: I think R always evaluates the expressions in both branches of `ifelse`, which might mean that the calculations are carried out for numbers that don't work, even if those are never going to be returned.

Comment: @Marius's point might help you use logic to figure out what's going on. Alternatively, as a more brute-force alternative, you could track the source of the error by using `options(warn=2,error=recover)` to go to the debugger when the warning gets triggered

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is happening because of the `ifelse`, as hinted to by the comment.

For illustration, see the following:

```
2^60 %% 349
[1] 210

2^61 %% 349
[1] 71
Warning message:
probable complete loss of accuracy in modulus 

msquare <- function(x,n) {
  message("msquare ", length(x))
  (x*x) %% n
}

mod.exp <- function(a,k,n) {
  print(k)
  ifelse(k <= 2,
     a^k %% n,
     ifelse(k %% 2 == 0,
            msquare(mod.exp(a,k %/% 2,n),n),
            (a * msquare(mod.exp(a,k %/% 2,n),n)) %% n))
}

# let's print the warning as it happens, without delay
powers <- withCallingHandlers(
  mod.exp(2, 1:62, 349), 
  warning = function(w) {
    print(w)
    invokeRestart("muffleWarning")
  }
)
```

You will see that you always have the full vectors in the branch operations and that the warnings are actually issued right up front, because large elements will still be sent into the `if-branch` as well (which gives you the examples at the top of my code excerpt).

Comment: Thanks. I don't completely understand this, but my take-away is that recursion + vectorization + ifelse don't mix very well. My naive view was that my recursive function was implicitly being called independently on each exponent in range `1:348`, but if the recursive call involves the full vectors at each stage, the overhead in all these function calls would more than negate any anticipated speed-up due to vetorization.

Comment: an interesting question is whether there's a good way to do vectorized operations with short-circuiting ...

Comment: @BenBolker at least one could write a `myIfElse(cond, yesFun, noFun)` with a similar behavior as e.g. `lapply` with the `FUN` argument, i.e. `myIfElse` would initialize the result, call the two functions passing the evaluated `cond` and assign the returns back into the result at positions according to `cond`